# I get error in code, I used glide and I tried to make an Image Adapter

Tags: android, android-glide

I get error in code, I used glide and I tried to make an Image Adapter The error is like that `.centerCrop()` is red and it suggest to me to change name Rename reference. I used latest android studio 4.3 and I used AndroidX in my project.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load("file://" + mAlbumImages.get(position).getAlbumImages())
            .centerCrop() //this line is red
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading)
            .crossFade()
            .into(viewHolder.imgAlbum);
    viewHolder.selectedOverlay.setVisibility(isSelected(position) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Which glide version you are using ?

I am using this one (latest)

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

and it's not showing error on `.centerCrop()`